# how to upload the single image from android app to nodejs server

Tags: android, node.js, image

I tried this program but I got a unexpected field error in server side while I receiving the image from app.can anyone solve this problem.I am waiting for your reply.Thanks in advance...

```js
nodejs code:

var express=require("express");
var bodyparser=require("body-parser");
var multer=require("multer");
var fs=require("fs");
var app=express();
var upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp/'});
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.post("/uploadimage",upload.single("file"),function(request,response)
{
    console.log("I got a request");
    var filepath=__dirname+"/imagesfolder/beta.jpg";
  fs.readFile(request.file.path,function(err,data)
  {
      if(err)
      {
          console.log(err);
      }
      else
      {
          fs.writeFileSync(filepath,data);
          console.log("successfully stored");
      }
  });
});
app.listen(8086,function()
{
    console.log("server running on port 8086");
});
```

Comment: Convert image to base64 string and upload to server.

Comment: bro i know how to convert the image base 64 string I have the code.you tell the code without  conversion try to find the error in this code. Thankyou for your concern.